# Batch script to match two filenames in the same folder with different extension

Tags: powershell, batch-file, ffmpeg

I've been looking, but I don't quite understand the regex of matching filenames. I have seen in SO that there are questions that match two filenames in different folders, but I'm looking within the same folder.

```
file01.jpg
file01.wav
file02.jpg
file03.jpg
file04.jpg
file04.wav
```

I want it to match if there is a `jpg` and a `wav` to run a ffmpeg script, and if the `wav` doesn't have a matching `jpg` then run another ffmpeg script, and if there is no matching `wav` to the `jpg` do another script.

```
if( $jpg == $wav ) // matching filenames without extension
    do script1
else if( $jpg != $wav ) // if there is no matching jpg to wav
    if( empty($jpg) && $wav )
        do script2
    if( empty($wav) && $jpg )
        do script3
```

Comment: That certainly isn't Windows Batch file code.

Comment: Neither is it Powershell. Please edit the question and add more details. A link to the answer you tried to work from would be a starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Powershell solution:

```
    set-location 'd:\mydirectory'

    $files      = ls "*.*"
    $dictionary = @{}

    foreach($file in $files) {
        $dictionary[$file.BaseName] += @( $file.Extension.ToLower() )
    }

    foreach($key in $dictionary.keys) {

        if( $dictionary[$key].Count -gt 1 ) {
            Write-Host $key ': wav and jpg'
        }
        elseif( $dictionary[$key] -eq '.wav' ) {
            Write-Host $key ': wav only'
        }
        elseif( $dictionary[$key] -eq '.jpg' ) {
            Write-Host $key ': jpg only'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided any code of your own, so I will only lead you in the right direction, and not give you a complete answer.

```
for %%i in (*.wav) do for %%a in (*.jpg) do if "%~ni"=="%~na" echo "%%i" = "%%a"
```

We just match the name only, excluding extension of all `wav` files by `%%~ni` with the name only, no extensions of all `jpg` files `%~na` and simply do something with the result, in this case I echo both files.

For a better understanding of how the variable handling works, in `cmd.exe` run `for /?`

Answer (score 0):

Just to make things simpler to understand, I thought I'd post a method which breaks this down into separate procedures for you.

The idea is to list the file names matching the extensions within individual holding files. Then use `FindStr` to determine which lists hold unique or duplicate names before deleting the holding files.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "sd=C:\SomePath\To\YourFiles"
Set "e1=.jpg"
Set "e2=.wav"

Rem change working directory to source directory
CD /D "%sd%" 2>Nul || Exit /B

Rem Write files names matching extension spec to .tmp files
For %%A in (%e1% %e2%) Do (For /F "Delims=" %%B In (
        'Dir /B/A-D-S-L "*%%A" 2^Nul') Do Echo "%%~nB")>"x%%A.tmp"

Rem %e1% files only, ["%%~A%e1%"]
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('FindStr /XLVIG:"x%e2%.tmp" "x%e1%.tmp"') Do (
    Echo %%~A%e1%
)
Echo(

Rem %e2% files only, ["%%~A%e2%"]
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('FindStr /XLVIG:"x%e1%.tmp" "x%e2%.tmp"') Do (
    Echo %%~A%e2%
)
Echo(

Rem Both %e1% and %e2% files, ["%%~A%e1%", "%%~A%e2%"]
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('FindStr /XLIG:"x%e2%.tmp" "x%e1%.tmp"') Do (
    Echo %%~A%e1%, %%~A%e2%
)
Echo(

Rem Delete the tmp files
Del "x%e1%.tmp" "x%e2%.tmp" >Nul 2>&1

Rem pause to show screen output
Pause
```

Just ensure that the location in line `2` is modified to match your source directory, to test it.

If you are happy that it has correctly identified the files, you can replace the `Echo` lines on `15`, `21` and `27` with your own commands, *(I have left the file names in brackets in the `Rem`arks as a reminder)*. You can optionally remove lines `17`, `23`, `29`, `34` and `35`, those containing `Rem`arks and any empty lines as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

An answer with both a batch and a powershell solution following similar routes.
Doing a dir with `*.jpg *.wav` and sorting by name.

The PowerShell script sorting -unique thus eliminating dupes and checking the existence of `.wav` and `.jgp`.

```
## Q:\Test\2018\05\24\MatchFiles.ps1
Get-ChildItem *.wav,*.jpg|Sort-Object BaseName -Unique|ForEach-Object {
    If ((Test-Path ("{0}.wav" -f $_.BaseName )) -and
        (Test-Path ("{0}.jpg" -f $_.BaseName )) ) {
        "$($_.BaseName) Both exist"
    } elseIF (!(Test-Path ("{0}.wav" -f $_.BaseName))){
        "$($_.BaseName).wav missing"
    } else {
        "$($_.BaseName).jpg missing"
    }
}
```

The batch variant also sorting but checking the output if previous entry had the same filename.

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\05\24\MatchFiles.cmd
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "Last="
For /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /B *.wav *.jpg^|sort') Do (
    If defined Last If "%%~nA" Equ "!Last!" (
        Echo %%~nA Both exist
    ) else ( 
        if "%%~xA" equ ".wav" (
            echo %%~nA.jpg missing
        ) else (
            if not exist "%%~nA.wav" echo %%~nA.wav missing
        )
    )
    Set "Last=%%~nA"
)
```

They share the very same output (added a single file05.wav for input):

```
file01 Both exist
file02.wav missing
file03.wav missing
file04 Both exist
file05.jpg missing
```